# Where do the builds go after the pipeline is run in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm very new to Azure DevOps. I'm running `npm run build` in the pipeline.

I'm wonder where the dist folder goes? How do I get access to it for further processing?
The build completes without error.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the agent you have 3 folders: `a` for artifacts, `s` for sources and `b` for binaries.

When the build start all the code downloaded to the `s` folder, so if you run `npm run build` the `dist` folder created there.

How do you access it? there are environment variables for all the folders, to the `s` folder the variable is `$(Agent.SourcesDirectory)`, so you can take the dist from there in another task by `$(Agent.SourcesDirectory)/Your App/dist` (or more deeper, depend your app structure).

You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables) the list of the environment variables.

Comment: Are you able to see these folders in the web interface or do you just have to reference them with the variables you mentioned?

Comment: You can't see them in the wen interface because you use Microsoft Hosted agents, after the pipeline it's removed. if you use private agent in your PC you can access them.